# Invalid currency "Arr" when modifying member profile

Tags: contacts

Why do I get this error message when simply modifying a contact?

Obviously there is no "Arr" currency in Civicrm. This is a new message.

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really an "answer" but we solved this issue by removing an extra '?' in a contribution amount field in the database. It seems that it comes from importing the contacts but the field was empty in the csv import file. :-/ the mystery is still there but the error message not.

Answer (score 1):

Looks the record has 'Arr' stored in currency field either in contribution or financial transaction table.

Comment: ok I'll have a look. I'm wondering how this happened

Comment: Any custom module?

Comment: it may be the currency that pirates use? how much is that ship? 'ohh, that be 7000 gold Arrs'

Comment: Currency store 3 chars and it got truncated from Array

Comment: Sept 19 *is* [talk like a pirate day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Talk_Like_a_Pirate_Day) so maybe it will fix itself on the 20th.